# Calculating large exponentiation in Golang

Tags: go, exponentiation

I've been trying to calculating `2^100` in Golang. I understand the [limit of numeric type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) and tried using `math/big` package. Here's what I've tried but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I've used [computation by powers of two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Computation_by_powers_of_2) method to calculate the exponentiation.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    two := big.NewInt(2)
    hundred := big.NewInt(50)
    fmt.Printf("2 ** 100    is %d\n", ExpByPowOfTwo(two, hundred))
}

func ExpByPowOfTwo(base, power *big.Int) *big.Int {
    result := big.NewInt(1)
    zero := big.NewInt(0)
    for power != zero {
        if modBy2(power) != zero {
            multiply(result, base)
        }
        power = divideBy2(power)
        base = multiply(base, base)
    }
    return result
}

func modBy2(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    return big.NewInt(0).Mod(x, big.NewInt(2))
}

func divideBy2(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    return big.NewInt(0).Div(x, big.NewInt(2))
}

func multiply(x, y *big.Int) *big.Int {
    return big.NewInt(0).Mul(x, y)
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

BigInt package allows you to [calculate x^y in log time](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Exp) (for some reason it is called exp). All you need is to pass `nil` as a last parameter.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(5), big.NewInt(20), nil))
}
```

If you are interested how to calculate it by yourself, take a look at my implementation:

```
func powBig(a, n int) *big.Int{
    tmp := big.NewInt(int64(a))
    res := big.NewInt(1)
    for n > 0 {
        temp := new(big.Int)
        if n % 2 == 1 {
            temp.Mul(res, tmp)
            res = temp
        }
        temp = new(big.Int)
        temp.Mul(tmp, tmp)
        tmp = temp
        n /= 2
    }
    return res
}
```

or play with it on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iPkJx35ysc).

Comment: That's true. It doesn't make much sense to take two `*big.Int` as the arguments. I like your approach.

Comment: @YeLinAung actually if at some point of time you will need big integers, you can modify it easily to do this. I wrote this function just to as a toy example, to make sure I understand the algorithm, but if need to use it somewhere in your production code, rather use default Exp method.

Comment: `new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(int64(a)), big.NewInt(int64(n)), nil)` is faster (and could be improved to not realloc the result, like the rest of the `math/big` routines do).

Comment: @DaveC if you would have read the whole answer, you would see that I wrote about it at the end. I included own implementation, because sometimes people learn how algorithms work and try to implement something by themself and in my opinion OP needed exactly this.

Comment: Yeah. I've been trying to solve the ProjectEuler problems with different approaches and trying learn go in the same time. That's why I am trying to implement the different `exponentiation`. On the other hand, I didn't notice the built-in method too. Thanks both of you. I've upvoted all the answers :)

Comment: shouldn't some Pow() function(s) be added to the go package "big" ? They would be handy! Any particular reason why Go authors did not add any pow() functions to that package? It exists in the math package for small numbers

Answer (score 14):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    z := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(100), nil)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

Output:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

Since it's a power of two, you could also do a bit shift:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    z := new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 100)
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

Output:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

Comment: That's a good one. I didn't see that while looking through the `math/big` package.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning immediately if `power % 2 == 0`. Instead, you just want to get the `result` of `base ** (power /2)`. Then multiply `result * result`, and if `power` is even then multiply `base` to that.

Comment: Oops. That'd be a mistake. I didn't mean to return immediately. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

To compute 2^100

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    n := big.NewInt(0)
    fmt.Println(n.SetBit(n, 100, 1))
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zzkAep-ylc)

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {

    bigx, power10 := new(big.Int), new(big.Int)
    var x int64
    bigx.SetInt64(x) //set x int64 to bigx
    power10.Exp(big.NewInt(10), bigx, nil) //power10 *big.Int points to solution

    str10 := power10.Text(10)
    fmt.Printf(str10) // print out the number and check for your self

}
```

Comment: Nice job, Tom! Thanks for the help pout in formatting.